# If a graph is k connected, then is it k+1 connected or k-1 connected? Or none?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

I am just wondering what can we conclude further if a graph is $k-\text{vertex}$ $-\text{ connected}$. This is just my personal doubt.

Before that I want to clarify the definition:

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph), it should has more than k vertices and remains connected whenever fewer than k vertices are removed. From my understanding, the definition implies that *there is a way to remove k vertices to disconnect the graph.* I want to clarify by "whenever" does it mean "any". Is it correct if I rephrase it as "it remains connected even if we remove any less than k vertices, but it can be disconnected if we remove k vertices"?

Now, I am wondering whether any of these statements is true?

1. If a graph is $k-\text{vertex}$ $-\text{ connected}$ then it is $(k+1)-\text{vertex}$ $-\text{ connected}$.
2. If a graph is $k-\text{vertex}$ $-\text{ connected}$ then it is $(k-1)-\text{vertex}$ $-\text{ connected}$.

In my opinion both are wrong, but I am not sure. Here are my reasons:

1. If a graph is $k-\text{vertex}$ $-\text{ connected}$ and if it is also $(k+1)-\text{vertex}$ $-\text{ connected}$ then there are $k$ vertices that you can remove to disconnect the graph which contradicts the definition of $(k+1)-\text{vertex}$ $-\text{ connected}$.
2. If a graph is $k-\text{vertex}$ $-\text{ connected}$ and if it is also $(k-1)-\text{vertex}$ $-\text{ connected}$ then there are $k-1$ vertices that you can remove to disconnect the graph, but again it contradicts the definition of $k-\text{vertex}$ $-\text{ connected}$.

The reason why I asked the above questions is because I encountered a proof about the statement "Suppose that $G$ is a nonplanar graph, $G$ contains no Kuratowski subgraphs, and that $G$ is minimally nonplanar.
Then G is at least 3-connected."

The proof says:

We again proceed by contradiction. Take any such graph G. We know from our
earlier proposition that this graph is at least 2-connected; let's assume for contradiction that it is exactly two-connected, and therefore that there is some pair of vertices $x$; $y$ such that deleting $x$ and $y$ from our graph disconnects it.

What confuses me is why do we need exactly 2-connected for a contradiction? The assumption says that it is at least 2-connected, the negation of that statement should be at most 1-connected, isn't it? I really need to understand what does at least 2-connected *imply* to really understand the logic of the contradiction.

Thanks for the help. It really confuses me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition implies no such thing. There is no such thing as "implying" in definitions. The definitions state what they explicitly state, and nothing more and nothing less.

---

*For example, if I say I am taller than $150$ centimeters, I **do not** imply that I am shorter than $151$ centimeters. The definition simply says that*

---

> No matter how you remove fewer than $k$ vertices, the graph remains connected.

This means that it should be easy for you to show that if a graph is $k$-connected, then it is also $k-1$ connected.

The reverse is of course not true, but your proof is not good. What you have "proven" is that a graph **cannot** be both $k$-connected and $k+1$ connected, which is not true (a counterexample of that is a full graph on $k+2$ vertices, for example)

---

There is also the concept of **exact** $k$-connectedness, and a graph is $k$-connected if it is $k$ connected, but it is not $k+1$ connected (and, consequently, the graph is $1,2,3,\dots,k$ connected, and is not $k+1,k+2,k+3\dots$-connected)

This is the concept used in your proof. You already know that the graph is $2$ connected (so it is also $1$ connected), now it can either be *exactly* $2$ connected or not. The proof shows that the graph *cannot* be exactly $2$ connected, so it must be $3$ connected.

Comment: Is there any other stronger definition of $k-$connected that says it is possible to have $k$ vertices removed for the graph to be disconnected? I think that definition is a bit too weak, I find it hard to use that in a proof.

Comment: @user338393 Read my answer to the end.

Answer (score 1):

A graph is $k$-connected if it has at least $k+1$ vertices and the removal of $k-1$ or fewer vertices leaves a connected graph.  For example, the star graph $K_{1,4}$ has a center vertex whose removal disconnects the graph.  So the star graph is not 2-connected.  However, it is 1-connected because it is connected.  The cycle graph $C_6$ is 2-connected because the removal of any vertex leaves a path graph on 5 vertices which is a connected graph.  Clearly, the cycle graph $C_6$ is also 1-connected since it is connected. The cycle $C_6$ is not 3-connected because removing the first and third vertex disconnects the graph and isolates the second vertex.

If removing any $k-1$ vertices leaves a connected graph, then removing any $k-2$ vertices also leaves a connected graph.  Thus, it follows from the definition that if a graph is $k$-connected, then the graph is also $(k-1)$-connected.  The converse is not true in general, as we saw above: $C_6$ is 2-connected but not 3-connected.  Of course, $C_6$ is 1-connected and also 2-connected, but if you pick the value of $k$ to be largest possible, then we can't go from $k$ to $k+1$ (but we can obviously go from $k$ to $k-1$).  In fact, the maximal value of $k$ for which a graph is $k$-connected is called the vertex-connectivity of the graph. For example, the vertex-connectivity of $C_6$ is equal to 2.